# Pthread Synchronization Issue

Tags: c, pthreads

What if all threads read a global variable which was assigned a value by the main() prior to the creation of the threads. Do we need any Mutex for synchronization?

Answer (score 1):

For reading the variable: no

For writing to and reading the variable: yes

Answer (score 1):

No.

A data race happens when multiple threads access a memory location (through a non-atomic value) and at least one of the accesses is a write and the operations are not ordered.

Since thread creation is a synchronization point, all the accesses after thread creation are ordered after the initial write access, and the later accesses are only reads. So there is no race.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the threads wants to change the value of your global variable then yes, you need a new mutex. Otherwise no synchronization is needed.